# Difficulty in solving calculus of variations problem.

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I am solving a problem on calculus of variation in which $F(x,y,y')$ is given as $F(x,y,y')=e^yy'^2$

After solving Euler equation I got this $2y'' +2y'-y'^2=0$.

I don't know how to proceed further.
Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might start by trying the substitution $u=y'$ so that you have a first-order differential equation?

Comment: @david holden I did that but the solution is getting complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the following differential equation you can use reduction of order here by letting $u = y',\ u' = y''$: $$2y'' +2y'-(y')^2=0$$ $$2u' + 2u - u^2 = 0$$ $$2\frac{du}{dx} = u^2 - 2u$$ $$\int\frac{2}{u^2 - 2u}du = \int dx$$ $$\int\left(\frac{1}{u-2}-\frac{1}{u}\right)du = x + C$$ $$\ln|u-2| - \ln|u| = x+C$$ $$\ln\left|\frac{u-2}{u}\right| = x+C$$ $$\frac{u-2}{u} = Ce^x$$ $$u-2 = uCe^x$$ $$u(1-Ce^x) = 2$$ $$u = \frac{2}{1-Ce^x}$$ Since $u = y'$, we can substitute to get: $$y' = \frac{2}{1-Ce^x}$$ $$y = \int\frac{2}{1-Ce^x}$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you Varun. I got the same but after integrating R.H.S I am not getting desired answer.

Comment: @zafran Take a look at [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B1-Ce%5E%7Bx%7D%7Ddx/?origin=button) to solve it.

Comment: Thank you. Actually it was an  incomplete question but it doesn't matter because I am having problem with solving this differential equation but it is not matching with given answer.